# Nested JSON string to Data Table

Tags: html, json, datatables

Please help.  I'm unable to match JSON parsed values to customer name using Data tables.  I was able to populate table column with contact info, but parsed data is identical for both accounts in the table created by code shown.  Is there a better way to loop through the data so it displays correctly.

I've seen a few examples of doing this with a simple table, but I would like to keep the sorting capability of Data Tables if possible.    Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Table 01</title>
</head>
<body>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="tableId" class="table table-condensed responsive"></table>

</body>
<script>

    var data01 = [
  {
  "name": "EXAMPLE Mickey",
  "due": "2018-11-22T19:00:00.000Z",
  "labels": [
    {
    "name": "Salesperson_1",
    "color": "green"
    }
    ],
  "pluginData": [
          {
          "value": "{\"billContact\":\"Mickey Mouse\",\"billCompany\":\"MM Clubhouse\"}",
          "access": "shared"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
  "name": "EXAMPLE Carl",
  "due": "2018-11-25T19:00:00.000Z",
  "labels": [
    {
    "name": "Salesperson_2",
    "color": "yellow"
    }
    ],
  "pluginData": [
          {
          "value": "{\"billContact\":\"Carl Grimes\",\"billCompany\":\"Rick's Group\"}",
          "access": "shared"
          }
      ]
  }
];


$('#tableId').DataTable({
  data: data01,
  "columns": [
    {"data": "name"},
    {"data": "due"},
    {"data": "labels.0.name"},
    {"data": "pluginData.0.value"},  
    {"data": function(){

      for (var i=0; i < data01.length; i++){
        var values = data01[i].pluginData[0].value;


        var parsedVal = JSON.parse(values);

        var contact = parsedVal.billContact;      

        return contact;

        //console.log(contact);
      }
    }}
  ]
});

</script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a function to a column, an argument is passed to that function which represents one entry of your data. So there is no need to iterate over your data by yourself, jQuery is doing that for you.

```
$('#tableId').DataTable({
  data: data01,
  "columns": [
    {"data": "name"},
    {"data": "due"},
    {"data": "labels.0.name"},
    {"data": "pluginData.0.value"},  
    {"data": function (row){

      let values = row.pluginData[0].value;

        let parsedVal = JSON.parse(values);

        let contact = parsedVal.billContact;      
        return contact;
    }}
  ]
});
```

If you do the iteration by yourself, the function will terminate at the return statement. So everytime the function is called it just see the first entry and return it and stop at that point.

Comment: Thank You flappix!  This works perfectly and is simpler than what I had.